# In need of service that can program my PIC10F200

Tags: pic

I have code from a electronics manufacturer that helps monitor SLA batteries and handles error codes. They recommended using a PIC10F200. I'm not really a programmer and don't want to invest in all the hardware just to get this code programmed on the PIC.

Does anyone know of a service or individual that can do this for me in very small quantity?

Comment: This question doesn't deal with with electronics design.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

The PICKit3 from Microchip costs about US$50.  You will be hard-pressed to find a service that will do it cheaper or faster for low quantities.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out a website like:

https://www.elance.com/

They have lots of people that do jobs like that.

If its simple downloading of code to the chip and the board is already made thats as simple as buying a programmer (under $100) and installing MPLAB (Free) and boom your done.

There is tons of information out there on how to go about programming the chips.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Microchip and many of the larger vendors like digikey will program your microcontrollers as a value-added service for orders of a certain size.  Probably run about a dime per unit.